# Найти наиболее длинный отрезок из двух значений в массиве

Tags: c++, алгоритм, golang

Дана строка чисел 6 2 5 **2 8 2 2 8 2** 6 8 ( длина 11 )
наиболее длинный отрезок из двух значений для данной строки будет **2 8 2 2 8 2** ( длиной 6 )
Как сделать это в коде, не понимаю, подскажите, если есть идеи какие то.
(желательно golang)

Answer (score 1):

Вашу задачу можно решить за O(n). Просто храните максимальный размер отрезка из нужных двух чисел, и "счётчик". Обе этих переменных изначально должны быть равны 0. Идите по массиву, и если текущий рассматриваемый элемент равен одному из тех двух чисел, прибавляйте к счётчику 1. Если вы встретили элемент, не равный тем двум числам, то текущий отрезок из подходящих чисел закончился. Тогда обновите максимальный размер отрезка, и присвойте счётчику значение 0. И так до конца. Потом после цикла нужно будет снова обновить максимальный размер отрезка. Потом выводите его.

Comment: А если числа изначально не известны, известны только длина и сам массив

Answer (score 1):

```
1)создать переменную содержащую длину самого длинног отрезка на данный момент -  `max = -1`\
2)создаьб переменную счетчик для текущей строки `currentLen = 0`\
3)создать переменную, отвечающую за хранение начала самой длинной последовательности `maxPosition` \
 `k = 0`\


 4)Считываем входную строку чисел `str`\
 5)ставим указатель `i` по строке на начальное положение

 6)считываем `str[i]` и `str[i+1]` если str[i+1] == str[i], то i+2 и т.д. , отдельный счетчик сделай\
 7)`k++`\
 8)если не дошли до конца строки `str` читаем `str[i+k]`\
 9)если `str[i+k]` равен `str[i]` или `str[i+1]` то `currentLen++` и к  п.7, иначе п.10\
 10)если `currentLen < max` то `max = currentLen`, `maxPosition = i`\
 11) если `i < длины строки-1` то `i++` и к п.6, иначе к п.12\
 12)конец
```

Этот алгоритм должен решать вашу задачу, разберитесь и реализуйте его

Comment: это не сработает для  `6 2 5 2 2 8 2 2 8 2 6 8`

Comment: @MBo исправил, соглсен

Answer (score 1):

Делаете два индекса - `left` и `right`, и словарь-счётчик `counter`, хранящий символы и для каждого счётчик количества в текущем окне, и счётчик `distinct` - количество различных символов в текущем окне.

Поставили `left` на нулевой индекс. Начали двигать right, на каждом шаге увеличиваем счётчик для очередного символа `counter[a[right]] += 1`.

Если новое значение этого счётчика стало равно 1 - увеличиваем `distinct`.

Если `distinct` стал равным 3, останавливаемся, и фиксируем разницу `right-left`, обновляем максимум длины интервала.

Теперь двигаем `left`, на каждом шаге уменьшая счётчик для очередного символа `counter[a[left]] -= 1`.

Если новое значение этого счётчика стало равно 0 - уменьшаем `distinct`.

Если `distinct` стал равным 2, останавливаемся,  снова начинаем двигать `right`

Алгоритм линейный